# Can't implement UIView subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to create a UIView which is basically a number with a circular background. I am using a UIView and applying a corner radius of half the dimension for the circle. Then I am adding the number as a UILabel subview to the above view.

What I want is close to this (without the fancy border):
(This is a screenshot from the app Count Battle).
[image: http://a3.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/ca/ea/a4/caeaa4a0-024d-e810-addb-17a12ea18000/screen568x568.jpeg]

Please help me rewrite by moving the code under the proper methods (drawrect, init, layoutSubviews, or any custom method). This is the code in it's current form. I think my understanding of this thing is muddled up, and this just doesn't look right.

This is the header file:

```
//  CircleNumView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CircleNumView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *circleColor;

- (instancetype)initWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius
                        center:(CGPoint)center
                          text:(NSString *)text;

@end
```

This is the implementation file:

```
//  CircleNumView.m

#import "CircleNumView.h"

@interface CircleNumView ()

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat radius;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;

@end


@implementation CircleNumView

// designated initializer
- (instancetype)initWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius
                        center:(CGPoint)center
                          text:(NSString *)text
{
    self = [super init];

    self.radius = radius;
    self.text = text;
    self.frame = CGRectMake ( center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);

    self.circleColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self = [self createView];

    return self;
}


- (CircleNumView *)createView
{
    CircleNumView *circularView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];

    circularView.backgroundColor = self.circleColor;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:circularView.bounds];
    label.text = self.text;
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [circularView addSubview:label];

    circularView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    circularView.layer.cornerRadius = self.radius;

    [self addSubview:circularView];

    return circularView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing everything pretty well until that `self = [createView];`

This is the implementation file that I would write:

```
//
//  CircleNumberView.m
//  
//
//  Created by James Valaitis on 13/04/2014.
//
//

#import "CircleNumberView.h"

#pragma mark - Circle Number View Private Class Extension

@interface CircleNumberView ()

/** The radius of this circular view.   */
@property (nonatomic, assign)       CGFloat             radius;
/** The number to present encapsulated as a string. */
@property (nonatomic, copy)         NSString            *text;
/** The label that shows the number contents of this view.  */
@property (nonatomic, strong)       UILabel             *textLabel;

@end

#pragma mark - Circle Number View Implementation

@implementation CircleNumberView

#pragma mark - Initialisation

/**
 *  Initialises a circlular view with a number in the middle.
 *
 *  @param  radius                  The radius of the circle.
 *  @param  center                  The center point of the circle in it's superview.
 *  @param  text                    The number as a string to present in the middle of this view.
 *
 *  @return An initialized object.
 */
- (instancetype)initWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius center:(CGFloat)center text:(NSString *)text
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        _radius = radius;
        _text = text;

        [self configureViewAndSubviews];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Property Accessor Methods - Getters

/**
 *  The label that shows the number contents of this view.
 *
 *  @return The label that shows the number contents of this view.
 */
- (UILabel *)textLabel
{
    if (!_textLabel)
    {
        _textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        _textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }

    return _textLabel;
}

#pragma mark - Subview Management

/**
 *  Configures this view as well as it's subviews.
 */
- (void)configureViewAndSubviews
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.radius;

    self.textLabel.text = self.text;
    [self addSubview:self.textLabel];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the rewrite! As they say hindsight is 20/20. Now I can't really explain why I didn't go this route from the very beginning.

Having said that, I am getting a square view instead of a circular view.

And, instead of (CGFloat)centre it will be (CGPoint)centre in the initializer.

Comment: Hey man, I've changed it with the updated fixes and grammatical corrections. Please try it now.

Comment: Thanks so much!! What a PITA a single line of code can be! LOL I hadn't noticed that you had forgotten to initialize the radius, and tried out countless variations in the meantime. Thanks again for curing me of some serious headache! :)